# Overwrite version from a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, versioning

Is it possible to overwrite a current version of a document from a workflow?  I need to update some fields in a list but when I update the fields versioning kicks in and changes the version number.  I want the version number to rename the same.  Versioning needs to stay switched on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()`

> Updates the item without creating another version of the item.

[SPListItem.SystemUpdate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.updateoverwriteversion%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[More Explanation](http://blog.amtopm.be/2011/09/06/update-vs-systemupdate-vs-updateoverwriteversion/)

Comment: Great thanks but how do I use this in the workflow?  Any examples :-)

Comment: how did you created your workflow, did you used SP Designer or Visual studio

Comment: Sharepoint Designer

Comment: @MikeBlair you will need to follow this post as you will need to create a custom workflow activity, get reference to your listitem it's running on and then update it manually, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/de558f74-5791-4b7f-bfb3-46fdd82c6957/sharepoint-designer-workflow-update-list-item-field-without-creating-new-version?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious  ,  search the article for item.SystemUpdate(); and change it with item.UpdateOverwriteVersion(); and it should work.

Comment: I don't have access to Visual Studio how can I implement a custom workflow activity?